# Capturing PHP request

Tags: php, apache, ip

Is there any way to capture the IP that is sending request to my php application.

This will be really helpful in preventing attacks from hackers. Recently I have created a portal to capture all the daily activities where port 80 got compromised because of a hacker sending a million packets per minute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why -1? this will be really helpful for me in protecting PHP pages from hackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to tell this from the apache logs and then Deny them from the httpd.conf file or .htaccess

Apache 2.2

```
Deny from 11.22.33.44
```

Apache 2.4

```
Require not ip 11.22.33.44
```

In PHP you can do

```
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

If you are going to try and block an IP using PHP you are not going to achieve much saving, as a script still has to be found, interpreted and executed only to then exit almost straight away, for each request a hacker makes.

It is far better to block the access earlier on in the process i.e. creating a blacklist of ip's in httpd.conf if you have access to it, or .htaccess if you dont.

Comment: If you want to block (and not just print) an IP in PHP, `if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "11.22.33.44") { die(); }`

Answer (score 0):

This will print out the user's IP address using PHP

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Thanks Richard and Srihari